# LoadLibrary MSVCRT Issue

Tags: dll, loadlibrary, msvcrt

There are two questions that confuse me:

1. I read from the Microsoft website that we can not use different C runtime in the same project. Say I have a dll compiled with /MT flag, then I can not use the dll in a /MD compiled project. My question is that if I use LoadLibrary() to load the dll, is it also necessary that I have the same C Runtime? What's the potential danger if I don't?
2. I think with the /MT flag, the runtime is statically linked into the binary file. But for one of my dll project, I made a dll with /MT. However, when I dumpbin.exe /dependents mydll, it shows that MSVCR100.dll is a dependent. My question is that why the dll is still dependent on MSVCR100.dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, that's not a requirement.  This happens in any program, the Windows DLLs use their own CRT for example.  Mixing CRTs in one program is however very dangerous and can cause very hard to diagnose problems.  The Windows apis were carefully designed to avoid those problems, they never require code to release memory that was allocated in a DLL, don't use exceptions, don't use standard C++ library classes, don't depend on locale or any other kind of shared CRT state.  The kind of things that go wrong when you mix.  Restricting yourself to a C or COM api helps a lot to avoid these traps.

2) This will happen when you link code that was compiled with /MD.  Common with .libs you link.

You stay out of trouble by always using /MD when you have DLLs in your project and compiling *all* code with the exact same compiler and options.  Static libraries you didn't build yourself are very troublesome, avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your 2. question, the dependency is indirect. Your DLL uses a DLL which depends on MSVCR100.dll. Using [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) you can see the dependency tree of your component and see which library is directly and indirectly dependent.